# How to make the site mobile friendly ,one option is to make mobile version of each

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new web: http://maybomtsurumi.com.vn. i want to make my video site mobile friendly.i am using webmatrix webpages to create site.please help me so that i can present my site to mobile users.

Very very thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this code in your website

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use CSS frameworks such as bootstrap to create your website rather than web matrix as bootstrap and such would be responsive and is really easy to use.

I also don't suggest creating a separate page for mobile users. I would use `viewport` to write a more responsive CSS.
P.S webmatrix will end its service on November 1st next year..

Answer (score 0):

@Nam Loan To make responsive site you are suppose to work on "Media Queries" for different devices to every class in your existing html.
For more detail you can check following link:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

media queries are good but they are bit hard for a noob. I can suggest you use CSS "Logically" and use HTML tags (like center) which can enable you to preview HTML like you would in a desktop browser and behave in the same way to a mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, bootstrap is a good framework to make responsive websites.

In short you can specify the width of each element in your webpage using columns. The width of these columns can be specified per screen size.

Alternatively you can define your own column sizes and use Media Queries to set the column sizes per a screen size in CSS.

I would strongly recommend using [W3 School](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/) for bootstrap tutorials.